# What causes test error 'Running without the SUID sandbox!'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, phantomjs, circleci

I'm running rails tests on Circle-CI. The test progress output contains a lot of messages as below. What do these mean, and are they caused by the app or the CI platform? Could an old version of PhantomJS raise this error?

```
[14462:14462:0812/100648:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(173)] Running without the SUID sandbox! See https://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxSUIDSandboxDevelopment for more information on developing with the sandbox on.
Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":99".
[14462:14462:0812/100648:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(219)] GLib-GObject: Attempt to add property GtkSettings::gtk-label-select-on-focus after class was initialised
[14462:14462:0812/100648:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(219)] GLib-GObject: Attempt to add property GtkSettings::gtk-entry-select-on-focus after class was initialised
[14462:14462:0812/100648:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(219)] GLib-GObject: Attempt to add property GtkSettings::gtk-entry-password-hint-timeout after class was initialised
Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":99".
[14489:14489:0812/100649:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(340)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process
[14462:14462:0812/100649:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(219)] GLib-GObject: Attempt to add property GtkSettings::gtk-button-images after class was initialised
[14518:14518:0812/100649:ERROR:renderer_main.cc(200)] Running without renderer sandbox
[14521:14521:0812/100649:ERROR:renderer_main.cc(200)] Running without renderer sandbox
[14524:14524:0812/100649:ERROR:renderer_main.cc(200)] Running without renderer sandbox
[14533:14533:0812/100649:ERROR:renderer_main.cc(200)] Running without renderer sandbox
[14538:14538:0812/100649:ERROR:renderer_main.cc(200)] Running without renderer sandbox
[14545:14545:0812/100649:ERROR:renderer_main.cc(200)] Running without renderer sandbox
[14462:14462:0812/100649:ERROR:extension_downloader.cc(695)] Invalid URL: '' for extension coobgpohoikkiipiblmjeljniedjpjpf
F[14702:14702:0812/100650:ERROR:renderer_main.cc(200)] Running without renderer sandbox
[14973:14973:0812/100651:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(173)] Running without the SUID sandbox! See https://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxSUIDSandboxDevelopment for more information on developing with the sandbox on.
Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":99".
[14973:14973:0812/100651:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(219)] GLib-GObject: Attempt to add property GtkSettings::gtk-label-select-on-focus after class was initialised
[14973:14973:0812/100651:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(219)] GLib-GObject: Attempt to add property GtkSettings::gtk-entry-select-on-focus after class was initialised
[14973:14973:0812/100651:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(219)] GLib-GObject: Attempt to add property GtkSettings::gtk-entry-password-hint-timeout after class was initialised
Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":99".
[0812/100651:ERROR:nacl_helper_linux.cc(303)] NaCl helper process running without a sandbox!
Most likely you need to configure your SUID sandbox correctly
```